# How do I knit in Rstudio?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

Everytime I click on knitr option in Rmarkdown, Rstudio starts installing knitr and Markdown and doesn't process my code. Please help me with a solution.

I am sure the codes written are correct. I have installed knitr, markdown and rmarkdown as well. But, I am not able to call knitr using "library(knitr)" function.

Comment: What is being printed in the "R markdown" pane (a tab next to Console)?

Comment: when I knit the code to Html, pdf or word, the below appears                            
  output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: default

Comment: I'm not referring to the source code that you have written - the tab that shows the compilation done when the Rmd file is rendered. Alterantively, what happens when you run `rmarkdown::render()` on the Rmd file manually?

Comment: That's the problem, compilation is not happening. I knit the codes and it starts installing the latest version of R markdown and knitr. rmarkdown: : render() is not happening.

Comment: The error I am getting is "Error: lazy loading failed for package 'knitr'"

Comment: Try starting up a new vanilla R session and reinstall knitr